# StreamWriter output BaseStream comes first

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, streamwriter

I have the below code for a SimpleHttp Server:

```
   using (Stream fs = File.Open(@"C:\Users\Mohamed\Desktop\Hany.jpg", FileMode.Open))
            {
                StreamWriter OutputStream = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(someSocket.GetStream()));
                OutputStream.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
                OutputStream.WriteLine("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
                OutputStream.WriteLine("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Hany.jpg");
                OutputStream.WriteLine("Content-Length: " + img.Length);
                OutputStream.WriteLine("Connection: close");
                OutputStream.WriteLine(""); // this terminates the HTTP headers

                fs.CopyTo(OutputStream.BaseStream);
                OutputStream.Flush();
                //OutputStream.BaseStream.Flush();
            }
```

The problem is when I see the output http response the headers are in the end of the text and the image binary from the BaseStream comes first even before the header. Sample of the output is(of course I removed the long bytes for the image):

```
    ä3ST)ëî!ðDFYLQ>qâ:oÂÀó?ÿÙHTTP/1.0 200 OK
    Content-Type: image/png
    Connection: close
```

What I want is to reverse the order and get the headers on top, to get is something like this:

```
    HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    Content-Type: image/png
    Connection: close
    ä3ST)ëî!ðDFYLQ>qâ:oÂÀó?ÿÙT4ñ®KÛ'`ÃGKs\CGÔ«¾+L»ê±?0Íse3rïÁå·>"Ü¼;®N¦Ãõ5¨LZÂµL¯
```

Using flush on the stream writer or on the BaseStream does not matter.
Any Help!

Comment: StreamWriter has a buffer, you have to Flush() it before you copy to its BaseStream.  Doing it after the copy is too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Kzrystof, I took your hint and it works now with flushing the StreamWriter before using copyTo, however I don't really know if this is correct thing to do? What do you think about it?

```
  using (Stream fs = File.Open(@"C:\Users\Mohamed\Desktop\Hany.jpg", FileMode.Open))
        {
            StreamWriter OutputStream = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(someSocket.GetStream()));
            OutputStream.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
            OutputStream.WriteLine("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
            OutputStream.WriteLine("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Hany.jpg");
            OutputStream.WriteLine("Content-Length: " + img.Length);
            OutputStream.WriteLine("Connection: close");
            OutputStream.WriteLine(""); // this terminates the HTTP headers
            OutputStream.Flush();

            fs.CopyTo(OutputStream.BaseStream);
            OutputStream.BaseStream.Flush();
            OutputStream.Flush();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by the call to CopyTo and by passing the BaseStream. It probably bypasses the StreamWriter that has not already flushed the data.

The BaseStream should not be used for writing. The StreamWriter has to be used.

```
using (StreamWriter outputStream = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(someSocket.GetStream())))
 {
    outputStream.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
    outputStream.WriteLine("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    outputStream.WriteLine("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Hany.jpg");
    outputStream.WriteLine("Content-Length: " + img.Length);
    outputStream.WriteLine("Connection: close");
    outputStream.WriteLine(""); // this terminates the HTTP headers

    string imageContent = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Mohamed\Desktop\Hany.jpg"));
    outputStream.Write(imageContent);
    outputStream.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a Stream I loaded the image to a byte array and used stream.Write but the output is incomplete. Original image size is 71KB the output is 15 bytes. 

byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Mohamed\Desktop\Hany.jpg");
OutputStream.Write(file);

Comment: I realize the StreamWriter does not have any Write method that accepts a byte array. I have edited my answer with the code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately, what the output now has full size, but it is completely binary, and Fiddler for is complaining about it, with a bad response that says it should start with HTTP/1.0 200 OK and end the headers section with CRLF.

Comment: You're welcome. We now know that BaseStream must not be used. I put back the StreamWriter in my answer and I converted the bytes of the image to the Base 64 encoding.

Comment: The last edit works, technically, but I get a corrupted file in the end. what do you thing about the answer I wrote?

Comment: I guess the Content-Length is not correct since the image was encoded using Base64. If it is working with the flushing, great :) It still feels weird accessing the BaseStream to write data...

Comment: Where do you take your `img.Length` from? Variable `img` is not declared anywhere. If I use `imageContent.Length` browser allows me to download file but it is corrupted and cannot be displayed.